# a question about method of moment estimator

Tags: method-of-moments, exponential-distribution

I have a question about method of moment estimator.

Say I have a IID sample $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ from an exponential distribution $Exp(\theta$), say I want to find the method of moment estimator of $\gamma = \theta^2$.

My question is can I find the method of moment estimator of $\theta$ first, and then take the power of 2 to be the method of moment estimator of $\gamma= \theta^2$?   (the reason I am asking this is because I am able to find the method of moment estimator of $\theta$ in the exponential distribution here, but I am not able to find the method of moment estimator of $\theta^2$ by equating the first two sample moments with the corresponding population moments. So I was thinking if it is fine or sufficient to just find the method of moment estimator of $\theta$ , then I can just take power of two of that to declare it as the Method of moment estimator of $\theta^2$. )

say if instead now I want method of moment estimator of another function of $\theta$, say $\sqrt\theta$, can I find the method of moment estimator of $\theta$, and then declare the square root of that as the method of moment estimator of $\sqrt\theta$??

OR SAY in general, if I have some function of $\theta$ (so in this case a parameter of the exponential distribution) say $f(\theta)= \sqrt{\theta^5}+3\theta^2$, is it allowed to first find the method of moment estimator of $\theta$ and that substitute that into $f$ to declare that as the method of moment estimator of $f(\theta)$?

Could someone provides some explanations?

Also I read a book (Page 292,  Introduction to Probability and Mathematical Statistics by Bain and Engelhart) little bit more, and it says this (probably it means you can first find the method of moment estimator of $\theta$  first, and then substitute that into the function to declare that as the method of moment estimator of that function of $\theta$). It is in the paragraph right after the example here:

(it says "Thus to estimate $\gamma(\theta))$, one might first solve...and then use $\gamma(\hat{\theta}$)"...)

[image]

Comment: Isn't this very similar to your previous question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435397/inverse-of-an-exponential-distribution